# How can I compile old Swift code with Xcode 7 beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am newbie to iOS development in Swift. Just started one day ago.

Currently I just tried the recent Xcode 7 Beta. Before I was installing Xcode 6.3, then I removed or uninstalled it because I was curious with Xcode 7 beta and its Swift version 2.

Having said that, I have a project which use old Swift code. The code base is pretty large, attempting to convert the old Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0 is breaking the code heavily. I am wondering if there is a way to compile or build my old project using Xcode 7 beta which support Swift 2?

I also would like to know if there is a way to back port current Xcode. Or Should I install back Xcode 6.3?

Comment: Just re-install Xcode 6.3 - both versions can happily co-exist.

Comment: @Paul R ah.. maybe there is no other way. since internet connection and unstable in my country sucks. it will take another 1 day to download.. =(

Comment: As a policy, I would suggest NOT deleting the current release version of Xcode. Beta versions have bugs. The very first beta version of a major release is likely to be buggy as hell. Plus, you won't be able to ship programs built with Xcode 7 until it is released - sometime this fall. Download Xcode 6.3 and use that. Keep Xcode 7 also. Use Xcode 7 to get familiar with the new features of Swift 2.0, but use Xcode 6.x for your day-to-day work.

Comment: You should ask questions about Apple beta productions at [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/). Apple not allow to discuss about beta software outside forums.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the top left menu...
Edit>
Convert> 
To the newest language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm both Xcode can coexist, only a caveat about cmd likens tools. for now keep 6,.4 tools. (for example binaries for git ..)